# Getting A Value From Response As A Function

Tags: php, facebook, graph

```
$args = array(
'name' => 'test',
'description' => 'xxxx',
'start_time' => 'xxxx',
'end_time' => 'xxxxx'
); 
$target_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/events";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Returns

```
 {"id":"xxxx"}
```

I Want this id as $id in php So i can use It further too..
thanks.

Comment: try `extract(json_decode('{"id":"xxxxxx"}', true)); echo $id;`

Comment: did you `echo $result` to get that return value

Comment: then where did you get `{"id":"xxxx"}`

Comment: wait will give you my complete code you can check.

Comment: $args = array(
    'access_token' => 'xxx',
    'name' => 'xxx',
    'description' => 'xxx',
    'start_time' => '2012-11-29T20:40:28+05:30',
    'end_time' => '2012-11-30T13:40:28+05:30'
); 
$target_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/events";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>

Comment: Run the After The event gets Created it shows response event id, I just want that event id as a function in php to use it furthr.

Comment: Got My Answer  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);  Added this Then $Object = json_decode($result);
$id = $Object->id;

echo $id;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use `json_decode` for this, check out this example:

```
$Object = json_decode($result);
$id = $Object->id;

echo $id; //return: xxxx
```

You can always just use $Object->id in place of resetting it to the $id variable, but it doesnt matter.

`json_decode()` documentation: https://www.php.net/json_decode

Comment: @user1863472 Updated my answer... $id will now have your `xxxx` value.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if understand what you are saying but if you are asking for a way to retrieve the value of your **id** you can always do the following

```
$_GET["id"] if GET Request was sent

$_POST["id"] if POST Request was sent
```

Comment: See This Response I am Getting In My Code {"id":"232767753520733"}, I Just want To Retrive this id in php as function...

Comment: so I can use that it furthr in php

Comment: Yes you can use this in further php code as a variable, You can store it in a var like this: $id = $_GET["id"]; and say echo $id;

Comment: Try, $simpleHTML = str_get_html($result); 
$id= $simpleHTML ->find('id');

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function str_get_html() in

Comment: To be able to use the str_get_html() function, you will need to first download a module which defines this function and include it at the top of your php script.

Heres the link(http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/simplehtmldom/1.5/simplehtmldom_1_5.zip/download) to download

Copy the simple_html_dom.php file to the folder where your script is and add the following line of code to the top of YOUR php script..

include('simple_html_dom');

Comment: You can retrieve the **id** from the **array** if it exists in the array.

Comment: what are the contents of the array?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$obj = json_decode($result);
$id = $obj->id;
echo $id;
?>
```

Comment: I slightly modified the answer, but it is still the same idea.